# MS Access 2003 - Information from a form output to a text file

Tags: ms-access, automation, vba

So I have this form that has tons of text boxes, combo boxes, etc. There is VB in the form's module that check to see if there are duplicates, and then run a few update queries to save the information in to tables. All that works great.

My question is what VB method can I use in this forms module to take information from all these objects (txt, cmb, etc) and output/save it into a text file?

I would just use as an example a form with the following three text boxes:

```
Text1 - String
Text2 - Date
Text3 - True/False
```

I know the vb for adding this to the database tables, but I am looking to be able to save the information in a text file, and then use the SendObject method to allow for these text files to be emailed from the field to the hq, and then placed in a larger db.

The outlook sendobject I think I have a pretty good handle on that portion, just need to figure out how to create a text file with the data in it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Forms are for entering data, not for sending to another database.

Comment: typically that is true, and admittedly this is weird, but the situation is what it is. I know this can be done (though it is a verys trange method), but because of the requirements versus resources, this is about the best way I have to get it done. There is actually another Access tool just like this one, however I did not create it. So I am just trying to figure out how I can get this done, in an weird but necessary way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your controls, textboxes, comboboxes, etc, bounded to a recordset? In this case, wouldn't you prefer to send related table records to whoever or whatever is concerned instead of collecting control's values throught text file? I mean this could be done, but I really find it weird!

EDIT: following @galleySlave comments, one idea would then be to write code similar to this one:

```
Dim m_dataInForm as string, _
    m_control as control

m_dataInForm = "Page Header"
for each m_control in screen.activeForm.section(1)
    m_dataInForm = m_dataInForm & m_control.caption & ": " & m_control.value & vbCr & vbLf
Next m_control
m_dataInForm = "Details"
for each m_control in screen.activeForm.section(o)
    m_dataInForm = m_dataInForm & m_control.caption & ": " & m_control.value & vbCr & vbLf
Next m_control
m_dataInForm = "Page footer"
for each m_control in screen.activeForm.section(2)
    m_dataInForm = m_dataInForm & m_control.caption & ": " & m_control.value & vbCr & vbLf
Next m_control
```

The `m_dataInForm` will then contain all data title (.caption) and value (.value). You might need some extra code to avoid errors on controls that do not have caption (like lines) or values (like labels) and/or to get the value in the expected format ('Yes' instead of -1). This will costs you a few extra instructions such as

```
SELECT CASE m_control.controlType
```

You'll then be able to send the `m_dataInForm` value either in a text message or save it as a file somewhere.

Comment: this is complicated. This has to be a simple remote MDE with no real linkage to tables, or networks...just in the Associates laptops. So this is possible, because I have seen it, in fact there is already a similiar MS Access tool at work utilized by a different division.

So none of these textboxes, combotexts, etc will be bound to a recordset...I have to do it all with code I guess? I know all the code (and it is a lot!!) for the ppt automation side of what I am trying to do, and I assume that if I can take all of this information and use code to work that side into ppt...

Comment: ...then I should be able to take all these values and enter them into a txt file. I know some of the automation for sending the email as well....just don't know how to work the attachment piece in the middle.

what if I create a select statement in the remote tool's code, without executing.....can I save the UPDATE SQL statement to a WORD doc, xls file, notepad, etc....what is the VB for that? think that would work

Comment: i agree that it is weird....its just the situation. I can't really wait until these associates get back from the field and just extract the information when they return, because I need about 10 different sets of data (overall process), and these guys are out for quite some time typically

Comment: thanks Philippe...Any and all advice I get here is always helpful. I appreciate it!!

Answer (score 2):

you could iterate through the collecton of controls on the form,
get the control's name & use select case to get the type of the control & get the appropriate value from it.

these pairs you can write to a string / text file which can then be made into the body of the mail.

Alternatively use the Access DoCmd.SendObject

```
DoCmd.SendObject acSendQuery, QueryName, acFormatXLS, emailAddress, "", "", "Form Data", "", 0
```

Where the QueryName is a query that extracts all of the info you need.
this will send it as an attached XLS file to the email.

Answer (score 2):

You want to Open a text file and use either the write # or print # statements.  Go into Access VBA and search in help on write.   You will find the Write # statement which will give you the necessary sample code.   You might want the print # statement depending on your requirements.